# Unable to Send JSON Data from C# to PHP Server

Tags: c#, php, json

I've been researching everywhere to solve this problem, but I keep running into a wall every time. Goal is to serialize data into a JSON string and send that data to a PHP file on the server. The end result is that the json_decode reads out null. I've been working on this for hours, any guidance or solutions from anyone would be greatly appreciated. Here's my code snippet.

```
private void sendData(string questionId, string youtubeUrl)
    {

        //fill in class data
        videoData vd = new videoData();
        vd.question_id = questionId;
        vd.video_path_on_server = videoId;

        //specifiy the url you want to send data to
        string phpurl = "http://questionoftheweek.local/video/save";

        //make request to url and set post properties
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(phpurl);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

        try
        {
            //serialize
            DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(videoData));
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            ser.WriteObject(ms, vd);

            string videodata = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
            writer.Write(videodata);
            writer.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to send data: " + ex.Message);
        }
```

And here's the PHP code on the server I'm using:

```
<?php
$json = json_encode($_POST);
var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

Comment: why are you encoding your $_POST ? can you paste var_dump of $_POST ? also check your json string is valid or not

Comment: I figured it out. I changed to DataContractJsonSerializer and now it works perfectly. Sorry, I'm an amateur at this. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `DataContractSerializer` Use `DataContractJsonSerializer` or `JavaScriptSerializer` in your C# code

[DataContractJsonSerializer Class Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx)
[JavaScriptSerializer Class Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)